# How to avoid inserting same data to the database from Excel

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-poi, spring-data-jpa

I have developed a rest API which read the data from excel and insert it to multiple database . now the problem with me is that i want to avoid the insertion of repeated data from excel. can someone suggest how to check repeatation of data when i m inserting one object per iteration

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/excel", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("organization") UUID organization,
                              @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    /*****GEt the organizaation id from form data and store to global variable*****/
    this.OrganizationID = organization;
    System.out.println("*****************************");

    /***Possible output parameters from file object***/

    /***Parameters required for S3 bucket upload***/
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
    InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
    String keyname = timeStamp+file.getOriginalFilename();
    String bucketname = "pharmerz-chat";

    /**Call S3 upload class and upload file**/
    amazons3.uploadfile(is, keyname, bucketname);
    /****Get organisation object from organisation id***/
    this.organization = iOrganizationRepository.findOne(organization);

    /**Excel File reader**/
    try {
        ExcelController ex = new ExcelController();
        File f1 = ex.convert(file);
        //     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E://Imp/Details.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f1);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        rowIterator.next();

    // while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        for(int i=1;i<=51;i++){
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //        System.out.println("cell.getStringCellValue().length() "+cell.getStringCellValue().length());
                //   if( cell.getStringCellValue().length()>0){
                List list = new ArrayList();
                //       This will change all Cell Types to String
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        String bstring = "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        list.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        System.out.println("boolean===>>>" + cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        String Nstring = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        list.add(Nstring);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        list.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                }
//                   }else {
//                       break;
                //        }
            }
            String productname = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String composition = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            String productcategeory = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            String uniqueproductcode = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
            String categeory = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
            String note = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();

            //         System.out.println(productname+"" +composition+"" +productcategeory+" "+uniqueproductcode+" "+categeory+" "+note);
            System.out.println("productname " + productname);
            System.out.println("composition " + composition);
            System.out.println("productcategeory " + productcategeory);
            System.out.println("uniqueproductcode " + uniqueproductcode);
            System.out.println(" categeory " + categeory);
            System.out.println("note " + note);
            ExcelController ex1 = new ExcelController();
            //  ex1.InsertRowInDB3(name,email,add,company);

            System.out.println("");
            //     Category categeoryobject=iCategoryRepository.findOne(UUID.fromString(CategeoryId));
            Category categeoryobject = iCategoryRepository.findByCategory(productcategeory);

            if(composition.isEmpty()){
                composition=null;
            }
            if(uniqueproductcode.isEmpty()){
                uniqueproductcode=null;
            }
            if(note.isEmpty()){
                note=null;
            }

            Product product = new Product();
            product.setProduct(productname);
            product.setComposition(composition);
            product.setCategory(categeoryobject);
            product.setUpc(uniqueproductcode);
            product.setNote(note);

            insertProduct(product, categeory);
        }
        workbook.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
  //      e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("data completed upload");
    }
}

/**Insert product into database***/
public String insertProduct (Product product, String categeory) {

    try{System.out.println("getProduct " + product.getProduct());
        System.out.println("getComposition " + product.getComposition());
        System.out.println("getCategory " + product.getCategory());
        System.out.println("getUpc " + product.getUpc());
        System.out.println("getCategory " + product.getCategory());
        System.out.println("getNote " + product.getNote());

        if (product.getProduct().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Product is empty");
            return "Product is empty";
        } else {
            Product savedproduct = iProductRepository.save(product);
            if (categeory.equalsIgnoreCase("Sale")) {
                Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
                supplier.setProduct(savedproduct);
                supplier.setOrganization(organization);
                iSupplierRepository.save(supplier);
                System.out.println("Product added to supplier " + categeory);
            } else if (categeory.equalsIgnoreCase("Purchase")) {
                Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
                purchaser.setOrganization(organization);
                purchaser.setProduct(savedproduct);
                iPurchaserRepository.save(purchaser);
                System.out.println("Product added to purchaser " + categeory);
            } else {
                Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
                supplier.setProduct(savedproduct);
                supplier.setOrganization(organization);
                iSupplierRepository.save(supplier);
                Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
                purchaser.setOrganization(organization);
                purchaser.setProduct(savedproduct);
                iPurchaserRepository.save(purchaser);
                System.out.println("Product added to both " + categeory);
            }

            System.out.println("product added");
            System.out.println("/************************");
            System.out.println(savedproduct.getId());
        }

        return "product added";}
        catch (Exception e){
      //  e.printStackTrace();
        return "all product finished";
        }
}

public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    convFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
    fos.write(file.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    return convFile;
}
```

Comment: Use Primary Keys or unique indexes. Then try to catch the uniqueness violation in the code. Seems about right ... If you introduce this check on the API level you will just introduce more round-trips to the DB, just to check this one thing per INSERT ..

Answer (score 2):

Put it also in the HashSet and check if your set already contains such rowdata before insertion

Comment: What about simple integrity constraints in the database tables, primary keys, etc.?

Comment: That would throw SQL Exception in Java code on insertion, maybe that's not what he is looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on database design and implement the data definitions correctly (e.g. what is the primary key for your record ...).  Without a correct relational DB design you can't use the declarative capabilities (i.e. no coding needed to implement) of Oracle (e.g. primary keys, ... ).

Having said that, you can remove dup's if you need by identifying the dups and deleting them, for example:

```
select c1, c1, c3 /* ... cn */ , count(*), min(rowid), max(rowid)
from t
group by c1, c1, c3 /* ... cn */
having count(*) > 1
;
```

Then delete the dups so that only 1 remains.